# Query IP geo-location data from bigquery open database: geolite2

Tags: go, google-bigquery, geolocation

What query can I use to get geo-location data of an array of IPs length >= 1 from [the bigquery open database: geolite2](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=geolite2&page=dataset&_ga=2.110883141.-1197906150.1568417357). The array is defined in a golang program. 
The error I get is: IP not defined at [11:77]

```
type IPValue struct {
    IP string
}

func main()  {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "{{project}}")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    q := client.Query(`
        WITH source_of_ip_addresses AS (
            SELECT @IPS as IPs
        )
        SELECT city_name
        FROM (
            SELECT ip, city_name, c, latitude, longitude, geoname_id
            FROM (
                SELECT *, NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(IP) & NET.IP_NET_MASK(4, mask) network_bin
                FROM source_of_ip_addresses, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(9,32)) mask
                WHERE BYTE_LENGTH(NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(IP)) = 4
            )
            JOIN ` + "`fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs`" + `
            USING (network_bin, mask)
        )
    `)
    q.DisableQueryCache = false
    q.Parameters = []bigquery.QueryParameter {
        {
            Name: "IPS",
            Value: []IPValue{
                {
                    IP: "75.x.y.z",
                },
            },
        },
    }
    runErr := runAndRead(ctx, q)
    log.Println(runErr)
}
```

Comment: Please mention what strategies you have tried so far and what are the problems you're facing.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Looks like a typo - your column name is `IPs`, not `IP` in `SELECT @IPS as IPs`, but then you use name `IP` in `NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(IP)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/geolocation-with-bigquery-de-identify-76-million-ip-addresses-in-20-seconds-e9e652480bd2

Query:

```
#standardSQL
# replace with your source of IP addresses
# here I'm using the same Wikipedia set from the previous article
WITH source_of_ip_addresses AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(contributor_ip, 'xxx', '0')  ip, COUNT(*) c
  FROM `publicdata.samples.wikipedia`
  WHERE contributor_ip IS NOT null  
  GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT country_name, SUM(c) c
FROM (
  SELECT ip, country_name, c
  FROM (
    SELECT *, NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip) & NET.IP_NET_MASK(4, mask) network_bin
    FROM source_of_ip_addresses, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(9,32)) mask
    WHERE BYTE_LENGTH(NET.SAFE_IP_FROM_STRING(ip)) = 4
  )
  JOIN `fh-bigquery.geocode.201806_geolite2_city_ipv4_locs`  
  USING (network_bin, mask)
)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
Query complete (20.9 seconds elapsed, 1.14 GB processed)
```

Comment: I have updated my question with what my code looks like. I get the error: unrecognized name as [11:77]. Please help me debug

Comment: Were you able to run my query as published? Try it first please

Comment: Yes I was. Very Impressive; It took 17 seconds

Comment: cool! so now we have to debug the code you pasted... maybe post a new question for that? (since the original question was answered here... now you just completely changed it)

Comment: I will leave it as is. This answer has helped me get from having no code to having some code, therefore still valid. Besides, the edits are available for anyone who wants to view the question's history. I had also mentioned my original intent was to do this with golang and that hasn't changed